# Why is the Y velocity in rigidbody2D changing with no reason?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game where the player is able to jump only when the
Y velocity==0, the player moves only on the X axis so I don't see a reason for the Y velocity to either decrease or increase. The problem is that it's weirdly changing.
Please help me fix that RigidBody2D velocity's problem, it's making me crazy.
Thanks.
[I'm showing you how the velocity is changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkFZn.png)[The Colliders of the objects that are causing this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAaAq.png)

edit: I restarted unity but it didn't work, even when I'm not moving the Y velocity is increasing.

Comment: Rigidbody velocities are basically never zero unless the rigidbody is sleeping. I would check `if(Mathf.Abs(rigidbody.velocity.y) < Mathf.epsilon)` but even that might be too restrictive. Try `if(Mathf.Abs(rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.01)` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should'nt compare float numbers because they are not fully precise.

Check IEEE 754 and instead of comparise them, check if it's greater than some value. Also look at you're y value in the rigidbody component to be sure.

Comment: That worked! I made the character able to jump if the Y velocity is bigger than 0.
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Check if the speed y is very small, as they suggested.
2. Use Freeze Position Y. By activating that box and deactivating it
   when you have to move vertically, for example to jump, you will be
   constrained to the Y axis, and therefore the speed will not change.

Good work!

Comment: Well I tried your 2nd suggestion before and unfortunately... It is somehow complicated to keep changing between freezing and unfreezing the Y position every time and I don't know how would it be after building it.
But the first one worked!
Thank you very much and I wish you a nice day!

Comment: @Tunisia I'm glad you found a solution. If you want, you can also accept the answer to help other users find the solution faster :)